# Suppressing output of module calling outside library

Tags: python, libsvm, pyml

I have an annoying problem when using machine learning library [PyML](http://pyml.sourceforge.net). PyML uses [libsvm](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/) to train the SVM classifier. The problem is that libsvm outputs some text to standard output. But because that is outside of Python I cannot intercept it. I tried using methods described in problem [Silence the stdout of a function in Python without trashing sys.stdout and restoring each function call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2828953/silent-the-stdout-of-a-function-in-python-without-trashing-sys-stdout-and-restori) but none of those help.

Is there any way how to do this. Modifying PyML is not an option.

Comment: have you check it , maybe it write in sys.stderr and not sys.stdout !!!

Comment: related: [Redirect stdout to a file in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22434262/4279) -- the file is `os.devnull` in this case.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Open `/dev/null` for writing, use `os.dup()` to copy stdout, and use `os.dup2()` to copy your open `/dev/null` to stdout. Use `os.dup2()` to copy your copied stdout back to the real stdout after.

```
devnull = open('/dev/null', 'w')
oldstdout_fno = os.dup(sys.stdout.fileno())
os.dup2(devnull.fileno(), 1)
makesomenoise()
os.dup2(oldstdout_fno, 1)
```

Comment: 'oldstdout = os.dup(sys.stdout)' throws a typeerror 'an integer is required'

Comment: figured it out, sys.stdout.fileno() and devnull.fileno() are required and it works after that, thanks!!

Comment: Shouldn't you close devnull at the end using `devnull.close()` or open it using the `with` statement?

Comment: Reid, your answer still does not work for me.
I needed a `os.fsync(devnull.fileno())` before the final dup2

To debug, try `import pybullet as pb` as the thing you want to silence :)

Comment: `os.dup2(0, 1)` on systems that don't have `/dev/null` :) (`os.dup2(sys.stdin.fileno(), sys.stdout.fileno())` more generally.)

Answer (score 5):

Dave Smith gave a wonderful answer to that on his [blog](http://thesmithfam.org/blog/2012/10/25/temporarily-suppress-console-output-in-python/). Basically, it wraps Ignacio's answer nicely:

```
def suppress_stdout():
    with open(os.devnull, "w") as devnull:
        old_stdout = sys.stdout
        sys.stdout = devnull
        try:  
            yield
        finally:
            sys.stdout = old_stdout
```

Now, you can surround any function that garbles unwanted noise into stdout like this:

```
print "You can see this"
with suppress_stdout():
    print "You cannot see this"
print "And you can see this again"
```

For Python 3 you can use:

```
from contextlib import contextmanager
import os
import sys

@contextmanager
def suppress_stdout():
    with open(os.devnull, "w") as devnull:
        old_stdout = sys.stdout
        sys.stdout = devnull
        try:  
            yield
        finally:
            sys.stdout = old_stdout
```

Comment: These solutions can only suppress output produced within python.

Comment: Probably, yeah. Also, I found that this solution fails to suppress some python output, for example the TQDM progress bar manages to print to Stdout even when within this context, not sure why. Still, I found that for most cases in Python, it works.

Comment: TQDM progressbar is printed to stderr by default to supress  it you would also need to redirect `sys.stderr`

Comment: @Majo that doesn't seem to work for me in a ipynb

Comment: The ipynb renders progressbar as `html` if I'm not mistaken. That means it cannot be suppressed by these means.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with portaudio/PyAudio initialization. I started with Reid's answer, which worked.  Although I needed to redirect stderr instead.  So, here is an updated, cross-platform version that redirects both:

```
import sys, os

# hide diagnostic output
with open(os.devnull, 'w') as devnull:
    # suppress stdout
    orig_stdout_fno = os.dup(sys.stdout.fileno())
    os.dup2(devnull.fileno(), 1)
    # suppress stderr
    orig_stderr_fno = os.dup(sys.stderr.fileno())
    os.dup2(devnull.fileno(), 2)

    print('*** stdout should be hidden!  ****')
    print('*** stderr should be too!  ****',
          file=sys.stderr)

    os.dup2(orig_stdout_fno, 1)  # restore stdout
    os.dup2(orig_stderr_fno, 2)  # restore stderr

print('done.')
```

Should be easy to comment out a part you don't need.

Edit: These might help, don't have time to look at the moment:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.redirect_stdout

Comment: This doesn't work on Windows, stdout and stderr do not get restored (the last print doesn't reach stdout).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and fixed it like that:

```
from cStringIO import StringIO

def wrapped_svm_predict(*args):
    """Run :func:`svm_predict` with no *stdout* output."""
    so, sys.stdout = sys.stdout, StringIO()
    ret = svm_predict(*args)
    sys.stdout = so
    return ret
```

Comment: This will work if svm_predict is the output comes from python but not if it comes from a shared library that python calls, which I believe is what the OP was asking about.

Comment: For me it worked using the Python bindings of *libsvm*. I guess for PyML the situation is similar. Stdout is a process property, i.e. my wrapping (as well as Ignacio's solution) perfectly works as long as external functionality is not used via subprocesses. It only would fail if someone opens `/dev/stdout` to write output to.

Comment: Which is exactly what most shared libraries do, which is why this solution will not work for most people. The above solution is going to be closer to what the requestor needs.