# Redirect stdout from python for C calls

Tags: python, stdout, io-redirection, dup2, dup

This is a follow up question from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5081657/572616) specifically concerning its [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5103455/572616).

---

From a python module I am calling a *Hello World* executable that simply prints `Hello World` to the stdout. I am interested in redirecting that output to a python `StringIO` and ran into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5103455/572616) answer which almost brings me all the way to the solution.

The critical part of this answer is this code segment:

```
1. def redirect_stdout():
2.     print "Redirecting stdout"
3.     sys.stdout.flush() # <--- important when redirecting to files
4.     newstdout = os.dup(1)
5.     devnull = os.open('/dev/null', os.O_WRONLY)
6.     os.dup2(devnull, 1)
7.     os.close(devnull)
8.     sys.stdout = os.fdopen(newstdout, 'w')
```

Also I would like to restore the stdout as it was before the redirection.

#### Questions

1. What exactly is going on in the function above?

   - What is `dup` and `dup2` doing?
   - What is `/dev/null`?
   - What is line 8 doing? (`sys.stdout = os.fdopen(newstdout, 'w')`)
2. How can I store the stdout in a `StringIO` object?
3. How can I restore the stdout after the call to my *Hello World* program?

I am pretty sure that once I have the answer for my question 1 that the answers of questions 2 and 3 will be easy. I decided to post them anyway to maybe push the answer of question 1 into the direction where I want to go.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I've written below a few additional comments that should make clearer what it's going on inside the `redirect_stdout` function:

```
def redirect_stdout():
    print "Redirecting stdout"
    sys.stdout.flush() # <--- important when redirecting to files

    # Duplicate stdout (file descriptor 1)
    # to a different file descriptor number
    newstdout = os.dup(1)

    # /dev/null is used just to discard what is being printed
    devnull = os.open('/dev/null', os.O_WRONLY)

    # Duplicate the file descriptor for /dev/null
    # and overwrite the value for stdout (file descriptor 1)
    os.dup2(devnull, 1)

    # Close devnull after duplication (no longer needed)
    os.close(devnull)

    # Use the original stdout to still be able
    # to print to stdout within python
    sys.stdout = os.fdopen(newstdout, 'w')
```

One important thing to note is that a process gets three different [file descriptors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor) from the OS when launched:

- stdin: 0
- stdout: 1
- stderr: 2

As explained in the comments, the code above takes advantage of the file descriptor for stdout and the file descriptor duplication functions to make trick the C code into using a different stdout while still keeping a reference to the original stdout in the python code to be able to print.

Comment: If I have redirected the stdout with `redirect_stdout`. How would I restore the stdout again so that external programs can print to stdout? `os.dup2(1, devnull)` does not seem to be working?!

Comment: It should be `os.dup2(newstdout, 1)`

Answer (score 7):

`/dev/null` is a special device file (everything in UNIX is a file!) that swallows everything written to it like a black hole. `dup` duplicates a file descriptor. If you are used to Windows, a file descriptor in UNIX is a special integer which represents an open file, it's like a Windows file handle.

The program is opening `/dev/null` for writing (only), taking a copy of it's file descriptor, closing the open file (because having a file descriptor is enough for UNIX to write to a file, you don't need to keep the resources open), then assigning the open file to `sys.stdout`.

Remember `sys` is the Python module which represents all sorts of system-specific resources, such as the file system. So, in UNIX `sys.stdout` will represent `/dev/stdout` i.e. the system `STDOUT` stream.

So, altogether, this code is fooling Python into thinking that `/dev/null/` is `STDOUT` so now every time your program writes to `STDOUT` with, say, the `print` statement (function in Python3) then it will really be writing to `/dev/null` and you will never see the resulting text on your console.

Answer (score -1):

See [manual pages](http://linux.die.net/man/2/dup) for the C runtime functions that underlie these Python functions.

Basically, they duplicate a file descriptor, into either a new file descriptor (with `dup()`) or into a file descriptor specified in the call, with `dup2()`.