# Unexpected redirect result with 2>&1 and command prompt

Tags: bash, shell

I was playing around with nc and since the -e command is gone, it recommended

```
cat /tmp/f | /bin/sh -i 2>&1 | nc -l 127.0.0.1 1234 > /tmp/f
```

I thought that the "2>&1" is unnecessary because I don't need to know the errors of the simple commands I was going to run like "whoami", "ls", etc. so my command instead is

```
cat /tmp/f | /bin/sh -i | nc -l 127.0.0.1 1234 > /tmp/f
```

But then, I don't get "clean" results. This is what I get

SERVER:

```
Listening on [0.0.0.0] (family 0, port 1234)
$  $
```

Client:

```
nc localhost 1234
ls 
testfile
whoami
user1
```

Basically, I don't see the $ in my client terminal. When I do the command with the 2>&1, I get what I expected

SERVER:

```
Listening on [0.0.0.0] (family 0, port 1234)
```

Client:

```
nc localhost 1234
$ ls 
testfile
$ whoami
user1
```

I know that 2>&1 means redirect stderr to stdout so in this case, how is the command prompt "$" part of the stderr? Shouldn't it be part of stdin?

Comment: `stdin` is what you type in the shell, so `$` can't be part of it. Where the prompt goes can be easily tested with `/bin/sh -i > /dev/null` and `/bin/sh -i 2>/dev/null`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shell uses the standard error stream for prompts, and also for menus created by `select`, and *any other text that is meant for interacting with the user*.

Comment: That is very interesting! Do you have documentation on this? I would like to read the motivation for this. I would have assumed that the prompts and menus would have been in stdout. Thanks for your comments.

Comment: @Arrow The POSIX standard is quite explicit about this: "Each time an interactive shell is ready to read a command, the value of this variable (`$PS1`) shall be subjected to parameter expansion and written to standard error."

Comment: Thank you. I truly did not know this nor expected it. My question has been answered by you.