# Blocking sys.stdout and stderr does not prevent C code from printing

Tags: python, c, output, cython

I am including in my python code a function compiled in `c` via a cython wrapper. I have to take that function as given and cannot change it. Unfortunately, when I run that function, I see output that is bothering me.

I have tried a lot of tricks that are supposed to get rid of it, all of which play with `sys.stdout` or `sys.stderr` -- most noteably, the new `contextlib.redirect_stdout`. However, nothing I tried managed to silence the output.

At the most basic level, I simply tried setting

```
    sys.stdout = open(os.devnull, 'w')
    sys.stderr = open(os.devnull, 'w')
```

Which is not a safe, or practicable way of doing it, but it should shut the function up. Unfortunately, I can still see the output. What am I missing? Is there perhaps another "output type" besides `stdout` that this function might be using?

If it helps, I am inside a Pycharm debugging session and see this output in my debugging console.

*Updated question to reflect that changing stderr did not help*

Comment: Maybe `stderr`…?

Comment: The `contextlib` module provides a `redirect_stdout` context manager which lets you *temporarily* redirect to `os.devnull` like you are doing. It also provides`redirect_stderr` if that's the file being written to.

Comment: you probably have to call another C function beforehand to close stdout. python stdout won't connect with generated code.

Comment: @deceze I tried shutting down stderr in a similar fashion (see update), function is still creating output as if its life depended on it.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre could you please elaborate?

Comment: I think it may be printing to the C stout/stderr (which aren't the same as the Python ones) (such is essentially what Jean-FrançoisFabre said earlier I think)

Comment: @DavidW They're the same, but it's also possible that the code is writing directly to the terminal.

Comment: @chepner If I understand right, the Python `sys.stdout`/`sys.stderr` wraps the C ones. So modifying the C ones will likely interfere with the Python but I don't think it'll work the other way around. I may not be right though - I try my best not to deal with this stuff if possible!

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/63328631/4657412?

Comment: @DavidW You are correct.  If you have a Python script that loads a C shared object but then hijacks `sys.stdout`/`stderr`, any stdout/stderr output from the C code will still get through.

Comment: OK, I see the distinction being made: there's file descriptor 1 (standard output, which is the same throughout the process, whether it's the Python interpreter or any shared libraries it links to), and then there's `sys.stdout` which is a Python object *initialized* to the same file handle but can be made to wrap a different handle.

Answer (score 2):

A C function prints to a file descriptor (1 for stdout, 2 for stderr). If you want to prevent the printing, redirect that FD, that can be done also temporarily. Here is a litte demo:

```
import os

STDOUT = 1 

saved_fd = os.dup(STDOUT)
null_fd = os.open(os.devnull, os.O_WRONLY)
os.dup2(null_fd, STDOUT)
os.system('echo TEST 1')    # redirected to /dev/null
os.dup2(saved_fd, STDOUT)
os.system('echo TEST 2')    # normal

# note: close the null_fd, saved_fd when no longer needed
```

---

If the C code opens the terminal device itself, there is very little you can do to prevent it. But that would be very unusual (I would even say a bug) unless there is a specific reason to do so.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there perhaps another "output type" besides `stdout` that this
> function might be using?

Yes, there exist `stderr`, which would be unaffected by stdout redirect, simple example, let `printer.py` content be

```
import sys
sys.stderr.write("printing to stderr")
```

then running in terminal

```
python printer.py > output.txt
```

lead to appearance of

```
printing to stderr
```

as `> output.txt` redirects only stdout.