# How to suppress stdout when using ctypes in python?

Tags: python, ctypes

I am writing some bindings for a c library using ctypes:

```
from ctypes.util import find_library
from ctypes import *


lib = find_library("lvm2app")

if not lib:
    raise Exception("LVM library not found.")

lvmlib = CDLL(lib)
```

It is all good, except the library prints to stdout every now and then and it is a bit annoying. Is there a way I can suppress these prints? Thanks.

Comment: This was answered in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5081657/how-do-i-prevent-a-c-shared-library-to-print-on-stdout-in-python

Comment: Thanks Barry, just what I was looking for.

Comment: No problemo. Clarification: answered *in depth* at the link mentioned.