# Python ctypes DLL stdout

Tags: python, ctypes

I am calling a DLL function from python using ctypes, and simply I want to capture the stdout from the dll call.  There are a lot of printf's I would like to redirect without changing the dll code itself.

How would I go about doing that?

Comment: Redirect the POSIX file descriptor (`os.dup2`) and also the Windows file handle (`kernel32.SetStdHandle`). See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17953864/205580).

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you'll need to make a [wrapper](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/729db35a-1508-48c9-a9f5-5724b515068b/redirection-of-stdout-and-stderr-from-a-dll?forum=vclanguage). Try something like this:

```
char* CallSomeFunc()
{
    ostrstream ostr;
    cout.rdbuf(ostr.rdbuf());
    SomeFunc();
    char* s = ostr.str();
    return s;
}
```

You will actually need to do something different with that string rather than returning it; I'll leave that part up to you. The string pointer becomes invalid as soon as it is returned, but you could do a fairly simple allocation as long as you deallocate the memory after it is returned.

Comment: So, that will have to be done in the c side of things - there is nothing I can really do from python to handle that?

Comment: It all depends on what you can access via `ctypes` - try the answer @eryksun commented above as well.