# How to redirect C-level streams in Python in Windows?

Tags: python, windows, redirect, stdout

Eli Bendersky has explained thoroughly how to "[Redirecting all kinds of stdout in Python](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2015/redirecting-all-kinds-of-stdout-in-python/)", and specifically Redirecting C-level streams, e.g. stdout of a shared library (dll). However, the example is in Linux and does not work in windows, mainly due to the following lines:

```
libc = ctypes.CDLL(None)
c_stdout = ctypes.c_void_p.in_dll(libc = ctypes.CDLL(None), 'stdout')
```

How can we make it work in Windows?

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer buried in [Drekin's code](https://github.com/Drekin/readline-hooks/blob/master/readline_hooks.py). Based on that, I made a small change to [Eli Bendersky's example](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2015/redirecting-all-kinds-of-stdout-in-python/):

Update: This code has been tested on Python 3.4 64-bit on Windows and Python 3.5 64-bit on Linux. For Python 3.5 on Windows, please see eryksun's comment.

```
from contextlib import contextmanager
import ctypes
import io
import os
import sys
import tempfile

import ctypes.util
from ctypes import *
import platform

if platform.system() == "Linux":
    libc = ctypes.CDLL(None)
    c_stdout = ctypes.c_void_p.in_dll(libc, 'stdout')
if platform.system() == "Windows":
    class FILE(ctypes.Structure):
        _fields_ = [
            ("_ptr", c_char_p),
            ("_cnt", c_int),
            ("_base", c_char_p),
            ("_flag", c_int),
            ("_file", c_int),
            ("_charbuf", c_int),
            ("_bufsize", c_int),
            ("_tmpfname", c_char_p),
        ]

    # Gives you the name of the library that you should really use (and then load through ctypes.CDLL
    msvcrt = CDLL(ctypes.util.find_msvcrt())
    libc = msvcrt # libc was used in the original example in _redirect_stdout()
    iob_func = msvcrt.__iob_func
    iob_func.restype = POINTER(FILE)
    iob_func.argtypes = []

    array = iob_func()

    s_stdin = addressof(array[0])
    c_stdout = addressof(array[1])


@contextmanager
def stdout_redirector(stream):
    # The original fd stdout points to. Usually 1 on POSIX systems.
    original_stdout_fd = sys.stdout.fileno()

    def _redirect_stdout(to_fd):
        """Redirect stdout to the given file descriptor."""
        # Flush the C-level buffer stdout
        libc.fflush(c_stdout)
        # Flush and close sys.stdout - also closes the file descriptor (fd)
        sys.stdout.close()
        # Make original_stdout_fd point to the same file as to_fd
        os.dup2(to_fd, original_stdout_fd)
        # Create a new sys.stdout that points to the redirected fd
        sys.stdout = io.TextIOWrapper(os.fdopen(original_stdout_fd, 'wb'))

    # Save a copy of the original stdout fd in saved_stdout_fd
    saved_stdout_fd = os.dup(original_stdout_fd)
    try:
        # Create a temporary file and redirect stdout to it
        tfile = tempfile.TemporaryFile(mode='w+b')
        _redirect_stdout(tfile.fileno())
        # Yield to caller, then redirect stdout back to the saved fd
        yield
        _redirect_stdout(saved_stdout_fd)
        # Copy contents of temporary file to the given stream
        tfile.flush()
        tfile.seek(0, io.SEEK_SET)
        stream.write(tfile.read())
    finally:
        tfile.close()
        os.close(saved_stdout_fd)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    f = io.BytesIO()
    print('...')

    with stdout_redirector(f):
        print('foobar')
        print(12)
        libc.puts(b'this comes from C')
        os.system('echo and this is from echo')

    print('Got stdout:"\n{0}\n"'.format(f.getvalue().decode('utf-8')))

    print('Resuming normal operation...')
```

Comment: For Python 2 `get_file_pointers_Python2`, which calls `PyFile_AsFile` is more reliable because `CDLL(ctypes.util.find_msvcrt())` may fail in embedding contexts that lack the SxS activation context to load msvcr90.dll. Also, the above code won't work in 3.5+, which uses the new CRT that doesn't have `__iob_func` and `find_msvcrt` returns `None` anyway. For 3.5+, use the code in `get_file_pointers_ucrtbase` that calls `__acrt_iob_func`.

Comment: FYI, `find_msvcrt` returns `None` in 3.5+ (and Steve Dower is pretty much committed to making it stay that way) because the new CRT is not a drop-in replacement for the old CRT and shouldn't be used with code that expects as much. For example, `ucrtbase.dll` doesn't export `printf`. It has `__stdio_common_vfprintf` which takes 5 parameters and requires building a `va_list`. Most code that relied on hacking the old CRT's private functions and structures, such as `__iob_func` and the `FILE` structure, no longer works because it was all reimplemented in C++.

Comment: Having issues making it work on Windows, can you please specify what lines need to be changed?

Comment: And Is there a way to monitor the stdout constantly, and not only specific functions?

Comment: also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17942874/stdout-redirection-with-ctypes

Comment: This solution no longer works, as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78037891/how-to-capture-a-dlls-stdout-stderr-in-python).