# Print an integer tensor in binary

Tags: python, tensorflow, binary, type-conversion, integer

I have a tensor of type `tf.int32`
I would like to use `tf.Print` but I need the result to be in binary.
Is this even possible?
It is for debugging.

Example:

```
constant = tf.constant(5)
#magic
tf.Print(constant) # prints 101
```

Comment: Your best bet may be to redirect the output from the C stream, modify it using python, and the print it as binary.  [See this post for details.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35304920/how-to-redirect-c-level-streams-in-python-in-windows)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`tf.py_function`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/py_function):

```py
x = tf.placeholder(tf.int32)
bin_op = tf.py_function(lambda dec: bin(int(dec))[2:], [x], tf.string)

bin_op.eval(feed_dict={x: 5})   # '101'
```

But note that `tf.py_function` creates a node in the graph. So if you want to print many tensors, you *can* wrap them with `tf.py_function` before `tf.Print`, but doing this in a loop may cause bloating.