# What is the best way to save tensor value to file as binary format?

Tags: python, tensorflow, floating-point

I'm trying to save tensor value to file as binary format.
Especially I'm trying to save float32 tensor value as binary format(IEEE-754 format). Could you please help me ??

```
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.constant([[1.0, 2.0, 3.0], [5.5, 4.3, 2.5]])

# how to save tensor x as binary format ??
```

Comment: See this question - https://stackoverflow.com/q/48123877/712995

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Print an integer tensor in binary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48123877/print-an-integer-tensor-in-binary)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The recommended approach is to checkpoint your model. As documented in the [Saving and Restoring programmer's guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/saved_model), you create a [`tf.train.Saver`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/Saver) object, optionally specifying which variables/saveable objects are to be saved. Then, whenever you want to save the values of the tensors, you invoke the save() method of the `tf.train.Saver` object:

```
saver = tf.train.Saver(...)

#...

saver.save(session, 'my-checkpoints', global_step = step)
```

.. where the second argument (`'my-checkpoints'` in the above example) is the path to a directory in which the checkpoint binary files are stored.

Another approach is to evaluate individual tensors (which will be NumPy ndarrays) and then save individual ndarrays to NPY files (via [`numpy.save()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.save.html)) or multiple ndarrays to a single NPZ archive (via [`numpy.savez()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savez.html) or [`numpy.savez_compressed()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savez_compressed.html)):

```
np.save('x.npy', session.run(x), allow_pickle = False)
```

Comment: thank you! I actually tried your suggestion and succeeded to store tensor as binary file. I evaluate all tensor first( calling sess.run() ) then store the array as binary format using python write function 
...
with open('bfile.bin', 'wb' ) as f:
f.write(numpy_array)

Comment: But what if you don't have access to the variable in the place `session` was defined?   I mean, the variable I want to save is a local variable.