# How do I save a multidimensional tensor in python?

Tags: python

What command should I use if I want to store a tensor in a file with dimensions greater than 2?

For example, if I have a four-dimensional array

`train = np.zeros([n1, n2, n3, trainnumber], np.float32)`

how should I save it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48144477/what-is-the-best-way-to-save-tensor-value-to-file-as-binary-format

Comment: Using [`np.save()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.save.html)?