# Best way a tensorflow tensor to file in Tensorflow 2.0?

Tags: tensorflow

What's the best way to save a tensorflow tensor to file in tf 2.0?

I see some answers to this, but they seem to be for tf 1.0

[What is the best way to save tensor value to file as binary format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48144477/what-is-the-best-way-to-save-tensor-value-to-file-as-binary-format)

Since they use sessions.

How would I say save something like

tf.constant([2, 3,4 2, 1])

to a file?

I think one way would be convert to a numpy, and then save to a file. But in cases where there are very large tensors, I may not have enough ram to copy all the values to a numpy array before saving it to a file.

Comment: Are you trying to save the `model` or `checkpoint`? Trying to understand the need to save a Tensor.

Comment: I will have training data stored in this tf.constant. The training pipeline will look up data from this tf.constant according to indexes in the training data tf.records. I am not trying to save a model or checkpoint

Comment: Did you consider storing the tensor's in `TFRecord` format?