# Using Ctypes in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ctypes

In Jupyter Notebook when i try to print *"hello world!"*  via  ***ctypes.cdll.msvcrt.printf***  function it turns length of the string. I am just trying to learn ctypes , and i wondered why does it happened ? Because if i try to execute that code in terminal it works well . And how can i use that function in Jupyter Notebook ?  The code is below.

```
import ctypes

ctypes.cdll.msvcrt.printf(b"Hello World")
```

Jupyter Notebook Cell output :

> 11

Normal Execution output :

> Hello World

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**IPython is not a real terminal.**

What IPython (the core in the Jupyter Notebook) does is capturing the `stdout`, `stderr` and other buffers before the data get printed out to the real terminal. That's happening on the Python level.

However `ctypes` does not print on the Python level with your code, it *uses a function* that's capable to print data. That function is present in a shared library in the system and is able to print on the C level (or better said via using a low-level print function from kernel mostly).

Regarding the `11` value, that might be the length of the result you get from the `printf()` function as you said i.e. `len("Hello World")` without the ending `\0` character, however it might even be the real output of the object that's supposed to represent the data printed out via `ctypes.cdll.msvcrt.printf()`. If the latter is the case, IPython properly captured the output, but `ctypes` just stored it in a different place (if at all).

I'm not on Windows, so can't say what's the result, but try to store it in a variable and then attempt to get its properties from which you might be able to retrieve the output and plug it back into the `stdout` for IPython:

```
out = ctypes.cdll.msvcrt.printf(b"Hello World")
dir(out)       # methods, properties, etc
vars(out)      # the whole dictionary structure (might fail)
out.__slots__  # __slots__ attribute in case __dict__ for vars() is not present
```

You can check [`capture_output()`](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/8ad12b0f8fbb2af5386ab31972fbc9889c3d1eb4/IPython/utils/capture.py#L124) here.

You might want to redirect out output from `ctypes` [to a file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17942874/5994041) or [to a buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17954769/5994041) you'd read from afterwards.

Comment: Is there a way to use **ctypes.cdll.msvcrt.printf** function in Jupyter ?

Comment: Sure, you'll either need to redirect it via a file or a buffer via ctypes or check the properties of the result you get back from `printf()`. Check the edited answer.

Comment: I didn't see your edit. Thanks. I suppose i understand.