# Getting output from "print" inside a function

Tags: python, python-2.7

Im using a library of functions that some of them print data I need:

```
def func():
   print "data"
```

How can I call this function and get the printed data into a string?

Comment: You can't... Try `return "data"` which is the only way to go. Unless you want to catch the output of **another python script**, then you can use `x = subprocess.Popen("python script.py", shell=True")` and then `x.stdout.read()`. **Might** (and i mean might.. only thought about it for a second) be able to use `eval()` to call the function and there catch the output.. But wouldn't reccomend it..

Comment: yes... well I want to avoid changing the library code. If ther really is no way, I will copy paste into my code and use `return`

Comment: When using Python3, you could override the `print` function and have it collect the data somewhere else.

Comment: this is python 2.7 let me retag..

Comment: That's true, you can do `sys.stdout = StringIO()` and print that normally ends up in `stdout` will be redirected..

Comment: `dis.dis()` also uses `print`; see the linked duplicate on how you could work around that.

Comment: If the library is implemented in C or starts a child process then you need to redirect at C level. See [How do I prevent a C shared library to print on stdout in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5081657/4279)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you can't change those functions, you will need to redirect `sys.stdout`:

```
>>> import sys
>>> stdout = sys.stdout
>>> import StringIO
>>> s = StringIO.StringIO()
>>> sys.stdout = s
>>> print "hello"
>>> sys.stdout = stdout
>>> s.seek(0)
>>> s.read()
'hello\n'
```

Comment: I could use this solution.. not very elegant though. thanks

Comment: If you want to use it Python3, you should change the 3rd line as "from io import StringIO", and the 4th line as "s = StringIO()".