# How do I block stdout from showing my password during my subprocess call in python?

Tags: python, subprocess

I want to block the output that becomes visible when I run `subprocess.call()`.
That's the only output I want to stop, because I need the commands that run after to display.

The call is showing my password which I have set as a system variable hidden as %%mypassword%% in the file getting executed (however, it shows up in the command line interface).

```
from subprocess import call
with open('//path/pwhold.txt','w') as pwhold:
        call(r"\\filetorun\%s.bat" % DB,stdout=pwhold)
os.unlink('//path/pwhold.txt')
```

This sort of works, but the file isn't deleted until after execution of the file is complete.

Are there any other ways to do this?

Comment: just use `os.devnull` instead of `'//path/pwhold.txt'` as said in [the page I've linked above](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11269627/4279).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per Sebastion's comments.  The interface used by `subprocess.call()` requires an actual file handle in order to capture the output at the OS level.  Attempting to use a string or string buffer fails when executing the command.

IGNORE:  This does not work:
Redirect STDOUT to a string instead of a file.  That way your information only appears in memory.  See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1218933/can-i-redirect-the-stdout-in-python-into-some-sort-of-string-buffer) question.

TLDR use:

```
from cStringIO import StringIO
import sys

old_stdout = sys.stdout
sys.stdout = mystdout = StringIO()
```

OR

```
from io import TextIOWrapper, BytesIO

# setup the environment
old_stdout = sys.stdout
sys.stdout = TextIOWrapper(BytesIO(), sys.stdout.encoding)
```

Comment: Replacing `sys.stdout` won't affect a child process. OP can [use `os.devnull` file instead](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11269575/how-to-hide-output-of-subprocess-in-python-2-7). In general, if you want to [redirect at C level, you need something like `os.dup()` on Unix](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17954769/4279) (it might work on Windows, I haven't tried)

Comment: You are right. but if you say mystdout = StringIO()  and then modify the call to be call(r"\\filetorun\%s.bat" % DB,stdout=mystdout)  this approach would work right?

Comment: after doing this: mystdout = StringIO() this did not work: call(r"\\filepathxxx\temp\%s.bat" % DB,stdout=mystdout) is that what you were talking about?  can you show me how this is implemented.

Comment: -1: it seems I wasn't clear enough. Your solution does not work. To see it, you could try to run any subprocess that prints something.

Comment: Thanks, the FNULL solution from other post "How to hide output of subprocess in Python 2.7"  works.:FNULL=open(os.devnull,'w'); subprocess.call(r"file.bat",stdout=FNULL,stderr=subprocess.STDOUT); FNULL.close()