# What is the equivalent of Python 3 sys.stdout.fileno() in Python 2

Tags: python, python-2.7, stdout, sys

I am working on a code in Python 2.7. I use a very specific library written partially in C with a Python API. This library uses *printf* to output to stdout. I would like to suppress that. I already found this question: [How do I prevent a C shared library to print on stdout in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5081657/how-do-i-prevent-a-c-shared-library-to-print-on-stdout-in-python) All of the provided answers use *sys.stdout.fileno()*. When I run my code I get:

```
original_stdout_fd = sys.stdout.fileno()
AttributeError: 'FlushingStringIO' object has no attribute 'fileno'
```

I suspect the problem is that I am using Python 2.7. Are my assumptions correct and is there a way to achieve this with Python 2.7?

Comment: `original_stdout_fd = 1` is likely to work too.

Comment: `sys.stdout` defaults to an instance of `file` in Python 2, not `FlushingStringIO` (whatever that is), so this isn't really a 2-vs-3 question.

Comment: `sys.stdout.fileno()` works in Python 2 as well; the problem is that the OP's code base has already replaced `sys.stdout` with an object of some other type that *doesn't* have a `fileno` method.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem on Python 2.7.10.

Comment: I see the problem now @chepner. Cant you think a way around it?

Comment: Not without knowing what `FlushingStringIO` is or why it is being used, short of just replacing `sys.stdout` with its original value (available from `sys.__stdout__`).

Comment: @chepner I do understand. Now that I know the problem is not Python version I found another possibility with wurlitzer.sys_pipes() from https://github.com/minrk/wurlitzer but it actually broke the functionality of https://github.com/flexible-atomic-code/fac which I suspect replaced sys.stdout in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that sys.stdout was replaced by FlushingStringIO by a library: https://github.com/flexible-atomic-code/fac. It also somehow depends on this detail and breaks otherwise. As there is no reasonable alternative to the library there is no way to suppress stdout output in this case.