# How to suppress C++ prints within Python script if it is not possible to get stdout file descriptor?

Tags: python, c++

I'm writing Python script in photogrammetry application *Metashape*. App is written in C/C++ and I would like to suppress all of its console output and make my own progress bar. There are several solutions proposed on how to suppress C++ prints within Python script, but all of those are based on an idea of getting file descriptor of standard output (`sys.stdout`). Python within `Metashape` is probably edited and built by `Metashape's` developers team so some functionalities are missing. There is no method `fileno()` in `sys.stdout` so I cannot get this file descriptor. I suppose I could hard code it, but this script if just a part of a bigger architecture and a lot of files are imported, exported and edited, so I suppose this is not a very good idea. This is probably the most promising solution I've find [link](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2015/redirecting-all-kinds-of-stdout-in-python/), but I am stuck at the beginning of it. Any ideas?

**Edit:**

Python version: 3.5.2 (default, Aug 28 2018, 15:41:10) [MSC v.1600 64 bit (AMD64)]

Note that in the script there are more than twenty C++ function calls that produce massive console output, so it would be ideal to make it possible to block and re-enable C++ output during the process. Also, any simpler solution, even if you ignore problem with non existing method `fileno()`, would be appreciated. There should be simpler solution to suppress C++ output within Python app

Comment: How is the C++ code interacting with the Python script?  Is it being called as a subprocess, or does this library provide a Python interface?

Comment: Metashape has Python API. Subprocesses wouldn't be big issue. Output could be piped to log file or `os.devnull`

Comment: You can redirect (OS-level) streams. You can also redirect to which stream C++'s `cout` etc write.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Can You please explain this a bit more. Also, note that I cannot edit C++ code

Comment: To be honest, I don't understand. If there's some code you can't change, then it's completely irrelevant that it's written in C++. How are calling that code? Is it a module? A subprocess? What is the relation to Metashape? Is that really relevant? Please also don't add "edit: ..." sections to your question, it should read a whole without picking bits and pieces from various locations.

Comment: To be honest, I don't understand. If there's some code you can't change, then it's completely irrelevant that it's written in C++. How are calling that code? Is it a module? A subprocess? What is the relation to Metashape? Is that really relevant? Please also don't add "edit: ..." sections to your question, it should read a whole without picking bits and pieces from various locations.

Answer (score 1):

You can access to console pane through `Metashape.app.ConsolePane` class or can just allow to create log file with `Metashape.app.settings.log_enable = True` and `Metashape.app.settings.log_path = '...\log.txt'` check the doc here: [Metashape python API doc](https://www.agisoft.com/pdf/metashape_python_api_1_6_5.pdf).

However you can also try to use solution described here: [How do I prevent a C shared library to print on stdout in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17954769/9145487) I just tested it on my stand alone Metashape python script and works really well. Metashape python api v. 1.6.5, Python v. 3.7.9

Comment: can you provide a sample code? I've tried to use `setValue` method for `Metashape.Settings` object and it doesn't seemed to work.

Comment: It looks like there is some but in Metashape.Settings object.
Instead of using `setValue` for setting your own setting the Agisoft team is proposing to create a custom .conf file. Check the thread here: https://www.agisoft.com/forum/index.php?topic=14234.0