# Disable ABSL_LOG() prints from C libraries in Python

Tags: python, stdout, abseil

One of the Python modules I use internally calls a C library interanlly that includes calls to `ABSL_LOG()`. This pollutes my stdout/err with lots of messages I don't want. I have been trying to redirect stdout/err using suggestions in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5081657/298209) but they don't seem effective for Abseil logs. Is there a more brutal way to disable these logs from python side?