How do I capture STDOUT of a shared C library, instead of printing just before exit?
I am calling a C library from Python, and trying to capture the library's STDOUT. My current approach is based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/17954769/3077823 with this code:
fd = sys.stdout.fileno()
old_stdout = os.fdopen(os.dup(fd), 'w')    
with open("_capture_stdout.log", 'w') as f:
    sys.stdout.close()
    os.dup2(f.fileno(), fd)
    sys.stdout = os.fdopen(fd, 'w')
    yield                                                                           
    os.dup2(old_stdout.fileno(), fd)
    sys.stdout.write("After!\n")
    sys.exit()

The "After!" message gets printed to STDOUT, and then the shared library's output is printed, just before the program exits. I suspect that the problem is buffering, but my tests of $ unbuffer ..., .fsync() and flushing have not helped. How can I capture the shared library's console at that point?

What is fd? If you want to duplicate stdout, it should be os.dup(1)

The basic problem is that Python has no control over the buffering that's going on within the library.

I don't understand why the library's output is being printed on the terminal at all. It should be going to _capture_stdout.log.

@Barmar It shouldn't be too hard to use ctypes to call setbuf(stdout, NULL);

Why not copy the linked code exactly? You missed the sys.stdout.close() # + implicit flush() that is called from  the _redirect_stdout function  The called C code is doing (e.g. fputs("blah",stdout)). Then, it returns. It's output is still stuck in the the FILE buffer. You have to fflush/fclose it. That's what the .close does [because python doesn't have a .flush???]. Then, reopen stdout.  _redirect_stdout must be called twice. The flush for the C output happens after you restore and goes to real stdout. I bet you get an zero length logfile

Thanks for the comments. I did not copy the linked code exactly, because it's badly written (e.g. stomps to in the outer scope, try / finally should be nested). That said, I've updated the code in my question to be clearer.

Ahh, this looks like it pulls all the suggestions together: https://gist.github.com/denilsonsa/9c8f5c44bf2038fd000f
