# Hide echo from apt-get in python

Tags: python, hidden, apt-get

How can i hide the process of installing java (apt-get openjdk-6-jre) when it's runned in python?
So i can replace it with
"Installing Java..." till it's ready.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Suppressing output of module calling outside library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4178614/suppressing-output-of-module-calling-outside-library)

Comment: You use `subprocess` or something like that to spawn a new process? If yes, just execute `<command_here> >/dev/null 2>&1` and print whatever you want.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an implementation of @khachik's comment:

```
import os
from subprocess import STDOUT, check_call

check_call(['apt-get', 'install', 'openjdk-6-jre'], 
           stdout=open(os.devnull,'wb'), stderr=STDOUT)
```

It raises an exception in case of an error.

Answer (score 1):

```
proc = subprocess.Popen('apt-get install openjdk-6-jre', stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                        stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
output, errors = proc.communicate()
return_Value = proc.returncode
```

This puts the program output into a string in Python, where you should probably check it for errors. See [subprocess docs](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html). (Unlike the redirect to /dev/null, this is cross-platform.)

Comment: `os.devnull` is cross-platform.