# Python flush ouput is not working with cffi library

Tags: python, logging, buffer, cffi

I have a weird behaviour using a Python application, (running under `supervisor`), that relies on a C library to initialize a component.

My problem is that **i cannot see** the output printed by this C library when i call a function there.

All the output in the application is managed with the `logging` module, and supervisor redirects it to a single log file.

So i thought this was just `flush` problem, and I tried the following:

```
lib.init_func()
sys.stdout.flush()
sys.stderr.flush()
```

But it doesn't work. I cannot see my `printf()` in the log file.

Also, I noticed that if i try to restart the application:
`sudo supervisorctl restart all`
The C library output gets finally flushed at the end of the log file !

Finally, setting `PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1` in supervisorctl makes it works, but i don't want to run my program unbuffered for performance issues.

--> Can someone explain why using `sys.stdout.flush()` after the call to the C library is not flushing it's output on my log file ?

Thanks !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In python, how to capture the stdout from a c++ shared library to a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24277488/in-python-how-to-capture-the-stdout-from-a-c-shared-library-to-a-variable)

Comment: Thank you, this is interesting !