# Capture stdout from C++ function on python side in pytest (pybind11)?

Tags: python, c++, pytest, pybind11

In C++, I have a class, and one of its methods (constructor, in this MRE) is supposed to print out something:

```
class Ex {
    std::string name;
    std::string content;

public:
    Ex(std::string content_, std::string name_){
        name = name_;
        content = content_;
        std::cout << "ASSIGNING" << std::endl;
    }
};

PYBIND11_MODULE(example, module_handle){
    module_handle.doc() = "Ex class.";

    py::class_<Ex>(
        module_handle, "PyEx"
    ).def(py::init<std::string, std::string>())
     ;
}
```

I then want to test this on the python side with pytest and attempt to capture stdout/err with `capsys`:

```
from build.example import PyEx
class TestExample:
    def test_type(self, capsys):
        ex = PyEx("foo", "bar")
        captured = capsys.readouterr()
        assert captured.out == "ASSIGNING"
```

However, `captured` ends up being empty: `CaptureResult(out='', err='')`:

```
>       assert captured.out == "ASSIGNING"
E       AssertionError: assert '' == 'ASSIGNING'
E         - ASSIGNING

test_init.py:7: AssertionError
----------------------------------------------------------------------------- Captured stdout call ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ASSIGNING
```

It's weird because it does print out "Captured stdout call". What am I missing

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In python, how to capture the stdout from a c++ shared library to a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24277488/in-python-how-to-capture-the-stdout-from-a-c-shared-library-to-a-variable)

Comment: c++ dumps directly to stdout, python only captures its own internal buffer that's buffering stdout

Comment: Minor nitpick: the name of your class and the constructor don't match. | Why do you need to test this from Python? Unit testing that class in pure C++ would seem the easier way. | What is the responsibility of that class? Why is it writing directly to `cout`? Wouldn't it make sense to abstract that, and allow dependency injection to make it easily testable?

Comment: @DanMašek Thanks, that's a typo I introduced while modifying the actual code to get a MRE. Fixing now.

I'm testing on the python side because there are some python libraries I use to extend the C++ classes I expose to python. 

I guess instead of writing to `cout`, it may be better if I figured out how to throw exceptions from the C++ side...

Comment: @AhmedAEK I did see this, but it's not immediately clear to me as to how I'd apply it to my case. I'll look into it in more detail.