# How to suppress tprintf from C library being used from Python

Tags: python, c, cython, tesseract

I am using a C library (tesseract) from my Python code. The C library has print [statements like these](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/blob/a3ba11b030345d32829b1e8355afea5419978d82/ccmain/osdetect.cpp#L293) that show up in my python program's stdout:

```
tprintf("Too few characters. Skipping this page\n");
```

Is there a way to suppress these print statements when using the C library from python? I've tried an approach I found on SO but it doesn't help. It does suppress `print "test"`, however, it doesn't suppress the output coming from `tprintf` in the C library.

I've tried the [solution mention here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4178614/suppressing-output-of-module-calling-outside-library) but it doesn't work. I still see output on the stdout.

```
devnull = open('/dev/null', 'w')
oldstdout_fno = os.dup(sys.stdout.fileno())
os.dup2(devnull.fileno(), 1)

tesseract = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary("/path/to/tesseract.so")
api = tesseract.TessBaseAPICreate()
rc = tesseract.TessBaseAPIInit3(api, TESSDATA_PREFIX, "osd")
tesseract.TessBaseAPISetPageSegMode(api, 1) #this line prints "Too few characters. Skipping this page" to stdout

os.dup2(oldstdout_fno, 1)
```

Comment: This looks relevant: https://sourceforge.net/p/tesseract-ocr/discussion/534361/thread/e95165c1/ (srderr, not stdout, and the option of specifying output to a file instead)

Comment: Can you set Tesseract variable, such as: `api.setVariable("debug_file", "/dev/null");` See https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/FAQ.