# How to I make python curses application pipeline friendly?

Tags: python, stdout, pipeline, curses

I am writing a python application that is intended to be used interactively inside unix pipelines. The application should fire up a curses based terminal UI, and based on user interaction, write to the standard output only right before exiting.

Typical usage would be that of a typical pipeline:

```
foo_command | my_application | sink_app
```

The problem I am having is that python curses library sends all sorts of things to stdout while the app is running. Furthermore, `sink_app` starts executing while `my_application` is running.

- How to I prevent curses from polluting stdout?
- How do I buffer the output and control when I want to flush it?
- Is it possible to control when `sink_app` starts executing and when it stops accepting input?

From what I gather, I need to save a reference to the stdout file descriptor so I can later write to it. And pass another fd (which one?) to ncurses. Supposedly through newterm(), but this isn't available on python curses binding.

Comment: An answer on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48697482/python-using-ncurses-when-underlying-library-logs-to-stdout shows how to call newterm from Python with ctypes.

Answer (score 4):

You could do this (setup a curses application in a **pipeline**) by using the [`newterm`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_initscr.3x.html#h3-newterm) function to directly open the terminal for managing the screen, while reserving *stdout* for the pipeline.  The [`dialog`](https://invisible-island.net/dialog/dialog.html) program does this.

But the Python curses interface does not have `newterm` (it only has [`initscr`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html#curses.initscr), which uses *stdout* for the screen...), and while there are probably workarounds (in Python, juggling the I/O streams), it hasn't been addressed in any of the answers on this forum.

Comment: Hey Thomas, thank you for the answer. I think we're on the right track. I believe such juggling you mention is implemented in [percol](https://github.com/mooz/percol). The relvant code is [here](https://github.com/mooz/percol/blob/d0bc902555fff5abef85012af3cbc323b915843b/percol/tty.py). The standard descriptors are taken from the *os* module and then there is some juggling with os.dup() and os.dup2().
But I don't quite grasp the whole thing.

Could you be so kind as to update your answer with a small example for stdout only?

Answer (score 2):

As [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53698417/1888983), juggling input streams. This is not well tested, but appears to be on the right track...

```
import os

# back up the piped stdin
mystdin_fd = os.dup(0)

# open the terminal for reading keyboard events
termin = open("/dev/tty")

# replace stdin with the terminal, so curses initscr() and getch() work
os.dup2(termin.fileno(), 0)

# initialise curses - https://docs.python.org/3/howto/curses.html
...

# read from the piped stdin
mystdin = open(mystdin_fd, 'r')
for line in mystdin:
    ...
```