# Python curses how to detect focus?

Tags: python, terminal, focus, ncurses

is there a key to detect when the terminal is focused?

For example the `KEY_RESIZE` is used to detect when the terminal is resized.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There's no predefined key, but with ncurses it is possible to define keys as done in the examples [`xterm-1002`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#tic-xterm-1002) and [`xterm-1003`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#tic-xterm-1003), which use this xterm feature

```
xterm+focus|xterm focus-in/out event "keys",
        kxIN=\E[I, kxOUT=\E[O,
```

documented in [*XTerm Control Sequences*](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h3-FocusIn_FocusOut).  There's no predefined *keycode*, but a program could

- ask ncurses for the string corresponding to `"kxIN"` with [`tigetstr`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_terminfo.3x.html#h3-Terminal-Capability-Functions) (noting that 0 and -1 are special values denoting failure),
- tell ncurses that this is really a key that [**`getch`**](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_getch.3x.html#h3-Reading-characters) should report as a *keycode*, using [`define_key`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/define_key.3x.html), and
- use [`key_defined`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/key_defined.3x.html) to retrieve the resulting keycode.

The ncurses test-program [`demo_defkey`](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/ncurses-snapshots/blob/master/test/demo_defkey.c) uses **`define_key`** and **`key_defined`** to demonstrate how to use these functions.  That's in C, of course.  From python that's also doable (see for example [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48697482/python-using-ncurses-when-underlying-library-logs-to-stdout/48698501#48698501)).

Other terminals implement a subset of xterm's control sequences.  OP comments about [`foot`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#tic-foot), which happens to recognize mode 1004 (focus in/out).  One could make a customized terminal description

```
foot-focus|foot with focus-in/out,
        use=xterm+focus, use=foot,
```

and use `tic` to compile that.  (Starting with the terminal description for `foot` is recommended; just setting `TERM=xterm-1002`, etc., tends to lead to [disappointment](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.faq.html#xterm_generic) on the part of users).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Is your suggestion terminal specific? I am not using xterm but foot.

Comment: Thank you very much for the info. From reading https://codeberg.org/dnkl/foot/issues/670 seems that focus-in/out should be supported in foot. But I do not understand which key code should I capture in python curses.

Comment: Thanks. Following you suggestions: `git clone https://github.com/ThomasDickey/ncurses-snapshots; cd ncurses-snapshots; ./configure; make; ./test/demo_defkey`
I do not sse any `kxIN` or `1002` keycode