# Suppress print output in unittests

Tags: python, python-2.6, python-unittest

**Edit:** Please notice I'm using Python 2.6 (as tagged)

Say I have the following:

```
class Foo:
    def bar(self):
        print 'bar'
        return 7
```

And say I have the following unit test:

```
import unittest
class ut_Foo(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_bar(self):
        obj = Foo()
        res = obj.bar()
        self.assertEqual(res, 7)
```

So if I run:

```
unittest.main()
```

I get:

```
bar # <-- I don't want this, but I *do* want the rest
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.002s

OK
Exit code:  False
```

My question is: Is there a way to suppress the output of the object being tested while still getting the output of the unittest framework?

**Edit**
This question is not a duplicate of the [flagged question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2828953/1393498) which is asking about silencing stdout of a particular function within a normal python script.

Whereas this question is asking about hiding the normal stdout of a python script while running it's unittests. I still want the unittest stdout to be displayed, and I don't want to disable the stdout of my tested script.

Comment: See this post on how to silence a function: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2828953/silence-the-stdout-of-a-function-in-python-without-trashing-sys-stdout-and-resto

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the question provided...

Answer (score 49):

Call your unittest with option "-b" - buffer stdout and stderr

## `Foo.py`

```
class Foo:
    def bar(self):
        print "bar"
        return 7
```

## `test.py`

```
import unittest
from Foo import Foo

class test_Foo(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_bar(self):
        obj = Foo()
        res = obj.bar()
        self.assertEqual(res, 7)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

## Run it with -b option

```
$ python test.py -b
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

OK
```

## Alternative: use `nose`

```
$ pip install nose
```

what installs command `nosetests`

Note, that I have modified test suite to have class and methods prefixed by `test` to satisfy `nose` default test discovery rules.

`nosetests` by default does not show output

```
$ nosetests
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.002s

OK
```

If you want to see the output, use `-s` switch:

```
$ nosetests -s
bar
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.002s

OK
```

Comment: Reference: https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#cmdoption-unittest-b

Comment: You can also use `unittest.main(buffer=True)` to have this as default

Comment: This works well with python 2.7 however I asked about python 2.6 which, sadly, does not support this option.

Comment: @user2016436 Sorry, I was not paying attention to all (very clearly stated) details of your question. You are right, that the `buffer` option was added at Python 2.7 and is missing in Python 2.6. However, the `nose` solution shall work (even though there might be slight differences in cornercases)

Comment: Note that `-b` helps suppressing python print statements, but not output from binaries called by the code for example using subprocess.run.

Answer (score 10):

You can suppress the output by disabling the sys.stdout and enabling it after your test is done:

```
import sys
import io
import unittest

class ut_Foo(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_bar(self):

        #You suppress here:
        suppress_text = io.StringIO()
        sys.stdout = suppress_text 
        
        obj = Foo()
        res = obj.bar()
        self.assertEqual(res, 7)
        
        #You release here:
        sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__
```

Got all of this from:

https://codingdose.info/2018/03/22/supress-print-output-in-python/

Comment: I found using the `with` statment and a mock, a better syntax, something like:
`with mock.patch('sys.stdout', new = StringIO()) as std_out:`