# Python/Flask Unittest, suppress Broken Pipe Error 32

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask, python-unittest, broken-pipe

When running unittests I often get `error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe`. It seems to be a harmless error that happens during testing, but I haven't been able to prevent or otherwise suppress it.

Some things that I have tried include changing `SIGPIPE` handling to `SIG_DFL` and running the app with `threaded=True`. If I were to `try/except` I don't know which code to wrap since this is in the context of unittesting.

I don't care about catching/preventing the error as much as just suppressing its output while all the other tests finish running. What else should I try?

Edit:

Here is some example code that often, but does not always result in the error:

```
  def test_register(self):                                                                              
    self.driver.get(self.get_server_url() + url_for(u'register'))                                       
    body = self.driver.find_element_by_id(u'body')

    username_input = body.find_element_by_id(u'username')                                               
    username_input.send_keys(self.USER1_DISPLAY_USERNAME)               
    privacy_policy = body.find_element_by_id(u'privacy_policy')                                         
    privacy_policy.click()
    #NOTE: not shown - more lines filling out form elements exactly like the above lines

    self.driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")                       
    register_button = body.find_element_by_id(u'onclick-register')                                      
    register_button.click()
```

And here is an example of the error message:

```
----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 44668)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 599, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 334, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 657, in __init__
    self.finish()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 716, in finish
    self.wfile.close()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 283, in close
    self.flush()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 307, in flush
    self._sock.sendall(view[write_offset:write_offset+buffer_size])
error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
----------------------------------------
```

This seems to only happen with integration tests. I'm using Selenium and a `LiveServerTestCase` with a `LIVESERVER_PORT` port set to `8943`. The mention of port `44668` in the error message looks suspicious.

My problem sounds exactly like [Suppress print output in unittests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24134343/suppress-print-output-in-unittests) but none of those solutions work.

Comment: What's the simplest test (and code) you can come up with that demonstrates the problems? Post that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution by redirecting `stderr` and `stdout`.

In `create_app()` add the following:

```
_stderr, _stdout = sys.stderr, sys.stdout                                                           
null = open(os.devnull,'wb')                                                     
sys.stdout = sys.stderr = null
```