# Suppress output in multiprocessing process

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have some code which runs in parallel using the multiprocessing Pool class. Unfortunately some of the functions I use from another library have some verbose output.  To abstract the problem have a look at the following example:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def f(x):
    print 'hello'
    return x*x

p = Pool(10)
p.map(f, [1,2,3])
```

So this will print 'hello' like 10 times. 
Is there a possibility to mute the output of the processes or
to put the std.out in some variable? Thanks for any suggestion.

EDIT:
I don't want to redirect the whole stdout, just for the processes of my pool.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Redirect stdout to a file in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4675728/redirect-stdout-to-a-file-in-python)

Comment: what about [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2829036/2395605)? It suggests a contextmanager.

Comment: It doesn't work I think the problem is that multiple independent processes are spawned.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [the `initializer` parameter](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.multiprocessing.Pool) to call `mute` in the worker processes:

```
import sys
import os
from multiprocessing import Pool

def mute():
    sys.stdout = open(os.devnull, 'w')    

def f(x):
    print 'hello'
    return x*x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Pool(10, initializer=mute)
    p.map(f, [1,2,3])
    print('Hello')
```

prints

```
Hello
```