# How to disable console output on exception in scipy.spatial.qhull.Delaunay?

Tags: python, exception, console, scipy, qhull

I have thousands of point sets which I feed to *Scipy's Delaunay* function to get a corresponding set of triangulations.

If my input points are invalid, ex. all points on a line or for some other reason the Delaunay triangulation fails, it result in a pretty detailed report in the console, like the following report:

> QH6154 qhull precision error: initial facet 1 is coplanar with the interior point
>   ERRONEOUS FACET:                                                                 
>   - f1                                                                             
>       - flags: bottom simplicial upperDelaunay flipped                             
>       - normal:   -0.3162  -0.9487        0                                        
>       - offset:    5929262                                                         
>       - vertices: p4(v2) p3(v1) p0(v0)                                             
>       - neighboring facets: f2 f3 f4                                               
>                                                                                    
>   While executing:  | qhull d Qbb Qt Qc Qz                                         
>   Options selected for Qhull 2012.1 2012/02/18:                                    
>     run-id 231396746  delaunay  Qbbound-last  Qtriangulate  Qcoplanar-keep         
>     Qz-infinity-point  _pre-merge  _zero-centrum  Qinterior-keep  Pgood            
>     _max-width 33  Error-roundoff 5.8e-009  _one-merge 4e-008                      
>     Visible-distance 1.2e-008  U-coplanar-distance 1.2e-008                        
>     Width-outside 2.3e-008  _wide-facet 6.9e-008                                   
>                                                                                    
>   The input to qhull appears to be less than 3 dimensional, or a                   
>   computation has overflowed.                                                      
>                                                                                    
>   Qhull could not construct a clearly convex simplex from points:                  
>   - p1(v3): 4.9e+005 6.1e+006 0.00016                                              
>   - p4(v2): 4.9e+005 6.1e+006    33                                                
>   - p3(v1): 4.9e+005 6.1e+006     0                                                
>   - p0(v0): 4.9e+005 6.1e+006 0.0009                                               
>                                                                                    
>   The center point is coplanar with a facet, or a vertex is coplanar               
>   with a neighboring facet.  The maximum round off error for                       
>   computing distances is 5.8e-009.  The center point, facets and distances         
>   to the center point are as follows:                                              
>                                                                                    
>   center point 4.9e+005 6.087e+006     8.25                                        
>                                                                                    
>   facet p4 p3 p0 distance=    0                                                    
>   facet p1 p3 p0 distance=    0                                                    
>   facet p1 p4 p0 distance=    0                                                    
>   facet p1 p4 p3 distance=    0                                                    
>                                                                                    
>   These points either have a maximum or minimum x-coordinate, or                   
>   they maximize the determinant for k coordinates.  Trial points                   
>   are first selected from points that maximize a coordinate.                       
>                                                                                    
>   The min and max coordinates for each dimension are:                              
>     0:  4.9e+005  4.9e+005  difference=   33                                       
>     1:  6.087e+006  6.087e+006  difference=   11                                   
>     2:         0        33  difference=   33                                       
>                                                                                    
>   If the input should be full dimensional, you have several options that           
>   may determine an initial simplex:                                                
>     - use 'QJ'  to joggle the input and make it full dimensional                   
>     - use 'QbB' to scale the points to the unit cube                               
>     - use 'QR0' to randomly rotate the input for different maximum points          
>     - use 'Qs'  to search all points for the initial simplex                       
>     - use 'En'  to specify a maximum roundoff error less than 5.8e-009.            
>     - trace execution with 'T3' to see the determinant for each point.             
>                                                                                    
>   If the input is lower dimensional:                                               
>     - use 'QJ' to joggle the input and make it full dimensional                    
>     - use 'Qbk:0Bk:0' to delete coordinate k from the input.  You should           
>       pick the coordinate with the least range.  The hull will have the            
>       correct topology.                                                            
>     - determine the flat containing the points, rotate the points                  
>       into a coordinate plane, and delete the other coordinates.                   
>     - add one or more points to make the input full dimensional.

According to the [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.Delaunay.html) there are no immediate option to set on the `Delaunay(...)` call to suppress this report. I haven't found an option either in the rather long list of [*qhull* options](http://www.qhull.org/html/qdelaun.htm).

I have tried the solution provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2828953/silence-the-stdout-of-a-function-in-python-without-trashing-sys-stdout-and-resto), but it seems to circumvent that.

Are there any way to suppress this?

Answer (score 1):

A way to fully suppress the warnings would be to use the [warnings](https://docs.python.org/2/library/warnings.html) class from the standard library.

An implementation, that is risky because you are ignoring all errors, which would suppress all output.  Your code would look like:

```
import warnings
import numpy
from scipy.spatial import Delaunay
#random point set
pts = numpy.random.rand(12,3)
#warnings catch - ignore filter
with warnings.catch_warnings():
    warnings.simplefilter("ignore")
    try:
        #call Delaunay with pts input
        out = Delaunay(pts)
    except:
        #when exception arises set out to False
        out = False
```

Keep in mind that it may be beneficial to modify the warnings, in order to print specific warnings at least once in case something unexpected arises.

Answer (score 0):

The following code suppresses most of the printing:

```
if points.shape[0]>3:
    tri = Delaunay(points, qhull_options='Pp')
```

using `qhull_options='QJ Pp'` will further suppress warnings, however it will also modify slightly the original position of the points to avoid precision and coplanarity issues.