# Redirect print command in python script through tqdm.write()

Tags: python, python-2.7, tqdm

I'm using `tqdm` in Python to display console-progressbars in our scripts.
However, I have to call functions which `print` messages to the console as well and which I can't change.
In general, writing to the console while displaying progress bars in the console messes up the display like so:

```
from time import sleep
from tqdm import tqdm

def blabla():
  print "Foo blabla"

for k in tqdm(range(3)):
  blabla()
  sleep(.5)
```

This creates the output:

```
0%|                                           | 0/3 [00:00<?, ?it/s]Foo
blabla
33%|###########6                       | 1/3 [00:00<00:01,  2.00it/s]Foo
blabla
67%|#######################3           | 2/3 [00:01<00:00,  2.00it/s]Foo
blabla
100%|###################################| 3/3 [00:01<00:00,  2.00it/s]
```

[According to the documentation of `tqdm`](https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm#writing-messages) the method `tqdm.write()` provides a means to write messages to the console without breaking the displayed progressbars.
Thus, the right output is provided by this snippet:

```
from time import sleep
from tqdm import tqdm

def blabla():
  tqdm.write("Foo blabla")

for k in tqdm(range(3)):
  blabla()
  sleep(.5)
```

And looks like this:

```
Foo blabla
Foo blabla
Foo blabla
100%|###################################| 3/3 [00:01<00:00,  1.99it/s]
```

On the other hand, there is this [solution which permits to silence those functions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2829036/3434933) by quite elegantly redirecting `sys.stdout` into the void.
This works perfectly well for silencing the functions.

Since I want to display the messages from these functions nonetheless without breaking the progress bars, I tried to merge both solutions into one by redirecting `sys.stdout` to `tqdm.write()` and, in turn, letting `tqdm.write()` write to the **old** `sys.stdout`.
This results in the snippet:

```
from time import sleep

import contextlib
import sys

from tqdm import tqdm

class DummyFile(object):
  file = None
  def __init__(self, file):
    self.file = file

  def write(self, x):
    tqdm.write(x, file=self.file)

@contextlib.contextmanager
def nostdout():
    save_stdout = sys.stdout
    sys.stdout = DummyFile(save_stdout)
    yield
    sys.stdout = save_stdout

def blabla():
  print "Foo blabla"

for k in tqdm(range(3)):
  with nostdout():
    blabla()
    sleep(.5)
```

However, this actually creates an even more messed up output as before:

```
0%|                                           | 0/3 [00:00<?, ?it/s]Foo
blabla


33%|###########6                       | 1/3 [00:00<00:01,  2.00it/s]Foo
blabla


67%|#######################3           | 2/3 [00:01<00:00,  2.00it/s]Foo
blabla


100%|###################################| 3/3 [00:01<00:00,  2.00it/s]
```

FYI: calling `tqdm.write(..., end="")` inside `DummyFile.write()` creates the same result as the first output which is still messed up.

I can't understand why this wouldn't work, since `tqdm.write()` is supposed to manage clearing the progress bar before writing the message and then rewriting the progress bar.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Redirecting `sys.stdout` is always tricky, and it becomes a nightmare when two applications are twiddling with it at the same time.

Here the trick is that `tqdm` by default prints to `sys.stderr`, not `sys.stdout`. Normally, `tqdm` has an anti-mixup strategy for these two special channels, but since you are redirecting `sys.stdout`, `tqdm` gets confused because the file handle changes.

Thus, you just need to explicitly specify `file=sys.stdout` to `tqdm` and it will work:

```
from time import sleep

import contextlib
import sys

from tqdm import tqdm

class DummyFile(object):
  file = None
  def __init__(self, file):
    self.file = file

  def write(self, x):
    # Avoid print() second call (useless \n)
    if len(x.rstrip()) > 0:
        tqdm.write(x, file=self.file)

@contextlib.contextmanager
def nostdout():
    save_stdout = sys.stdout
    sys.stdout = DummyFile(sys.stdout)
    yield
    sys.stdout = save_stdout

def blabla():
  print("Foo blabla")

# tqdm call to sys.stdout must be done BEFORE stdout redirection
# and you need to specify sys.stdout, not sys.stderr (default)
for _ in tqdm(range(3), file=sys.stdout):
    with nostdout():
        blabla()
        sleep(.5)

print('Done!')
```

I also added a few more tricks to make the output nicer (eg, no useless `\n` when using `print()` without `end=''`).

/EDIT: in fact it seems you can do the `stdout` redirection after starting `tqdm`, you just need to specify `dynamic_ncols=True` in `tqdm`.

Answer (score 15):

It might be the bad way, but I change built-in print function.

```
import inspect
import tqdm
# store builtin print
old_print = print
def new_print(*args, **kwargs):
    # if tqdm.tqdm.write raises error, use builtin print
    try:
        tqdm.tqdm.write(*args, **kwargs)
    except:
        old_print(*args, ** kwargs)
# globaly replace print with new_print
inspect.builtins.print = new_print
```

Comment: No that's not bad at all, very interesting approach. Thank you for registering and posting it!

Comment: AFAIK this is the solution in Ptyhon 3.x, but not in Python 2.6/2.7.

Comment: I find this doesn't work well with IPython auto-reload - if I edit any part of the source file that contains `inspect.builtins.print = new_print` then I get a segfault in ipython the next time I try to run any code from that file.

Comment: I don't know enough about overwriting library functions, but I'm certain that using unqualified "except" statements is terrible practice for lots of reasons - for example, it catches literally any exception, including keyboard interrupts! Better to work out what exceptions might be thrown and catch those specifically.

Answer (score 14):

By mixing, user493630 and gaborous answers, I created this context manager which avoid having to use the `file=sys.stdout` parameter of `tqdm`.

```
import inspect
import contextlib
import tqdm

@contextlib.contextmanager
def redirect_to_tqdm():
    # Store builtin print
    old_print = print
    def new_print(*args, **kwargs):
        # If tqdm.tqdm.write raises error, use builtin print
        try:
            tqdm.tqdm.write(*args, **kwargs)
        except:
            old_print(*args, ** kwargs)

    try:
        # Globaly replace print with new_print
        inspect.builtins.print = new_print
        yield
    finally:
        inspect.builtins.print = old_print
```

To use it, simply:

```
for i in tqdm.tqdm(range(100)):
    with redirect_to_tqdm():
        time.sleep(.1)
        print(i)
```

To simplify even further, it is possible to wrap the code in a new function:

```
def tqdm_redirect(*args, **kwargs):
    with redirect_to_tqdm():
        for x in tqdm.tqdm(*args, **kwargs):
            yield x

for i in tqdm_redirect(range(20)):
    time.sleep(.1)
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 4):

OP's solution is almost correct. The test in tqdm library that messes up your output is this one (https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm/blob/master/tqdm/_tqdm.py#L546-L549):

```
if hasattr(inst, "start_t") and (inst.fp == fp or all(
           f in (sys.stdout, sys.stderr) for f in (fp, inst. 
    inst.clear(nolock=True)
    inst_cleared.append(inst)
```

`tqdm.write` is testing the file you provided to see if there is risk of collision between the text to print and potential tqdm bars. In your case stdout and stderr get mixed in the terminal so there is a collision. To counter this, when the test passes, tqdm clears the bars, prints the text and draws the bars back after.

Here, the test `fp == sys.stdout` fails because `sys.stdout` became `DummyFile`, and fp is the real `sys.stdout`, so the cleaning behavior is not enabled. A simple equality operator in `DummyFile` fixes everything.

```
class DummyFile(object):
    def __init__(self, file):
        self.file = file

    def write(self, x):
        tqdm.write(x, end="", file=self.file)

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return other is self.file
```

Also, since print passes a newline to `sys.stdout` (or not depending on the user choice), you don't want tqdm to add another one on its own, so it's better to set the option `end=''` than performing `strip` on the content.

#### Advantages of this solution

With gaborous's answer, `tqdm(..., file=sys.stdout)` pollutes your output stream with pieces of bar. By keeping `file=sys.stdout` (default), you keep your streams separated.
With Conchylicultor and user493630's answers, you only patch print. However other systems such as logging directly stream to sys.stdout, so they don't go through `tqdm.write`.

Comment: However, the modified `write` function did not work for me, I think because the line gets overwritten with the progress bar before the newline is added

Answer (score 1):

Just adding my solution for future bypassers.

```py
import sys
import time
from tqdm import tqdm

def blabla():
  print("Foo blabla")

for i in tqdm(range(5), file=sys.stdout):
    time.sleep(.5)
    print('\r\033[2K\033[1G', end='', flush=True) # Cursor up one line and carriage return
    blabla()
```

Will give you the wanted output:

```
Foo blabla
Foo blabla
Foo blabla
Foo blabla
Foo blabla
100%|█████████████████████████████████████████████| 5/5 [00:02<00:00,  1.99it/s]
```

This will still doesn't work great in an IDE like a Jupyter Notebook, but in a terminal, this should give you the wanted output.

(`tqdm==4.66.1`)

Comment: Could you add more context and elaborate on the solution. It remains unclear to me how it solves the problem of external functions calling `print()` within a `tqdm` loop? I.e. if I were able to alter the third party functions to use `tqdm.write()` instead of `print()`, I could directly `tqdm.write()` to `stdout`.

Comment: @PierreSchroeder You are right. I updated my answer to a better, still simple solution.

Answer (score 0):

I used the solution of @gaborous (https://stackoverflow.com/a/37243211/17419428 - Best answer so far). It worked like a charm for print instructions with just one argument. However, in my case, it introduced newlines characters when using print instructions with several arguments, such as:

```
print('1','2','3')
```

> 1
> 2
> 3

The solution (after reading and trying several alternatives) was to use *args and **kwargs arguments. My complete solution is (which I now notice it is very similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/42424890/17419428):

```
class DummyFile(object):
    file = None

    def __init__(self, file):
        self.file = file

    def write(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['file'] = self.file
        kwargs['end'] = ''

        # I had to print each argument separately, with kwargs['end'] = ''
        for i in args:
            tqdm.write(str(i), **kwargs)

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return other is self.file

    def flush(self):
        pass

@contextlib.contextmanager
def nostdout():
    save_stdout = sys.stdout
    sys.stdout = DummyFile(sys.stdout)
    yield
    sys.stdout = save_stdout

def blabla():
  print("Foo blabla", "same line")

# tqdm call to sys.stdout must be done BEFORE stdout redirection
# and you need to specify sys.stdout, not sys.stderr (default)
for _ in tqdm(range(3), file=sys.stdout):
    with nostdout():
        blabla()
        sleep(.5)
```