# How to keep tqdm progress bar on the bottom of the terminal?

Tags: python, terminal, printing, carriage-return, tqdm

Here is the code

```
def download_from_dict(path_link_dict, folder)
    counter = 0
    for path, link, name in tqdm(path_link_dict):

        counter = counter + 1
        if os.path.isfile(folder + path + name):
            print('[ Already there! ] ' + name)
            continue

        if not os.path.isdir(folder + path):
            os.makedirs(folder + path)

        response = requests.get(link, headers=HEADERS)
        with open(folder + path + name, 'wb') as file:
            file.write(response.content)
        print('[*] Downloaded ' + name)
```

output is

```
progress bar..
[*] Downloaded something..
Progress bar..
[*] Downloaded something
```

desired output( I want the bar to stay on the bottom of the terminal. )

```
[*] Downloaded something
[*] Downloaded something
[*] Downloaded something
progress bar..
```

I have tried using the leave=False, position=0, and barfmt.. parameters for the tqdm function, but it didn't work
I also have tried using \r before [*] Downloaded, but the bar is longer than the printed statement so it clears only a part of it.
I have gone to the tqdm docs, and i couldn't solve this problem
can you help?

Answer (score 0):

it is not an easy and straightforward solution in here, but there are interesting discussions and solutions on how to do that on a couple of previous questions here in stackoverflow: [Redirect print command in python script through tqdm.write()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36986929/redirect-print-command-in-python-script-through-tqdm-write/37243211)
and [python progress bar using tqdm not staying on a single line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38766681/python-progress-bar-using-tqdm-not-staying-on-a-single-line)

It is also going to depend if you require it in the standard terminal or jupyter notebook or another output...

Comment: Thanks, but I ended up using rich.progress.track.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the using `tqdm.write()` instead of `print()`, but I suggest instead of adapting your code to fit the library, use a library specifically designed for your use case. The library for this is [Enlighten](https://pypi.org/project/enlighten/)

You'd replace the above code with (contents of the for loop are unchanged):

```py
import enlighten

MANAGER = enlighten.get_manager()

def download_from_dict(path_link_dict, folder)

    pbar = MANAGER.counter(total=len(path_link_dict), desc='Downloading', unit='files')

    for path, link, name in pbar(path_link_dict):

        if os.path.isfile(folder + path + name):
            print('[ Already there! ] ' + name)
            continue

        if not os.path.isdir(folder + path):
            os.makedirs(folder + path)

        response = requests.get(link, headers=HEADERS)
        with open(folder + path + name, 'wb') as file:
            file.write(response.content)
        print('[*] Downloaded ' + name)
```

You can find more information and options for customization in the [documentation](https://python-enlighten.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html).

Also take a look at [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) to simplify your file operations.