# progress bar is printed multiple times, but I need it once only

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, progress-bar

I have tried virtually everything, but the progress bar is appearing at each iteration anew, see the link at the bottom of this question. How can I achieve the all progress goes to the first progress bar right under the code ? Is it due to  placement of this: `pbar.update(1)` ?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from tqdm import tqdm
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error

# Initialize RSI-related variables
rsi_values = []

# Define the parameters
num_epochs = 40
batch_size = 64
initial_balance_usd = 110000  # Initial balance in USD
minimum_buy_fee = 52  # Minimum buy fee
buy_fee_percentage = 0.03  # Buy fee percentage
minimum_sell_fee = 63  # Minimum sell fee
sell_fee_percentage = 0.027  # Sell fee percentage
rsi_period = 14  # RSI calculation period (e.g., 14 days)

# Define a list of sequence lengths to experiment with
input_sequence_lengths = [16]

# Define URLs for historical data of different time series
urls = [
    ["C:/Users/max2/Desktop/12.xlsx", 2],
]

total_iterations = 50

# Define a list of weight_rsi values to experiment with
weight_rsi_values = [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5]

# Initialize a dictionary to store results for each weight_rsi value
results = {}

# Initialize the progress bar at the very top
with tqdm(total=total_iterations, desc="Processing") as pbar:
    for weight_rsi in weight_rsi_values:
        pbar.update(1)
        print(f"Training with weight_rsi={weight_rsi:.10f}")
        # Loop through each URL and process the data separately
        for url_info in urls:
            print(f"Processing data from URL: {url_info}")
            url = url_info[0]
            action = url_info[1]

            if action == 0:
                print(f"Executing command A for URL: {url}")
                df = pd.read_csv(url, header=None, skiprows=1)
            elif action == 2:
                df = pd.read_excel(url, skiprows=1) 
            else:
                print(f"Executing command B for URL: {url}")
                df = pd.read_excel(url, header=None, skiprows=1)

            # Rest of your data processing and modeling code goes here

            # Access the second column (all rows) and convert it to a list
            if action == 2:
                column_b_values = df.iloc[:, 1].tolist()
            else:    
                column_b_values = df.iloc[:, 1].tolist()

            # Initialize RSI-related variables
            price_changes = np.diff(column_b_values)
            gains = price_changes.clip(min=0)
            losses = -price_changes.clip(max=0)

            avg_gain = np.mean(gains[:rsi_period])
            avg_loss = np.mean(losses[:rsi_period])

            # Train and evaluate the models for each sequence length
            for sequence_length in input_sequence_lengths:
                print(f"Training and evaluating model for sequence length: {sequence_length}")
```

[The output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KLpBX.jpg)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Redirect print command in python script through tqdm.write()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36986929/redirect-print-command-in-python-script-through-tqdm-write)

Answer (score 0):

tqdm doesn't handle printing to the console and requires redirection, and even when you use the redirection, it can quickly get overwhelmed.

Consider using [Enlighten](https://pypi.org/project/enlighten/) instead since it handles printing to console natively.

Just replace

```py
with tqdm(total=total_iterations, desc="Processing") as pbar:
```

with

```
import elighten

manager = enlighten.get_manager()
with manager.counter(total=total_iterations, desc="Processing") as pbar:
```

If you want to customize the format or add color, take a look at the [documentation](https://python-enlighten.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html).