# Remove output of all subprocesses in Python without access to code

Tags: python, subprocess, stdout

In Python I'm using

```
sys.stdout = None
```

before some calls that I don't control. These calls may call some subprocesses that write to stdout.

How can I avoid this subprocesses calls to write to stdout?

Again, I don't have ownership of the code that calls the subprocess.
It seems subprocess.Popen (and similar) doesn't honor sys.stdout.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2828953/silence-the-stdout-of-a-function-in-python-without-trashing-sys-stdout-and-resto
Does this do the trick?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, redirecting `sys.stdout` only works for python prints. When a sub-process is invoked through `subprocess`, python doesn't capture the output by default, and leaves the process execute normally. There's no way to remove the output from the process easily.

I suppose you could create a `subprocess.py` file at the same level as the python code you cannot change (or before the official `subprocess.py`) to change `Popen` contents, but that would mean import the official module from your stub module, hardcoding python path, ... Doable, but there's a simpler approach.

Here's a quick hack for python 3 that I tested and which works:

- locate the file `subprocess.py` in the python installation and copy it aside the module that you cannot change (on my machine `C:\python34\lib\subprocess.py`)
- add just one line in that file

the code (around line 750):

```
def __init__(self, args, bufsize=-1, executable=None,
             stdin=None, stdout=None, stderr=None,
             preexec_fn=None, close_fds=_PLATFORM_DEFAULT_CLOSE_FDS,
             shell=False, cwd=None, env=None, universal_newlines=False,
             startupinfo=None, creationflags=0,
             restore_signals=True, start_new_session=False,
             pass_fds=()):
    """Create new Popen instance."""

    _cleanup()
```

now add (before `_cleanup()`):

```
    stderr = stdout = DEVNULL
```

that forces standard output and error to null device: no output

now the drawbacks:

- dependent of the installed python version. Could work with other versions but it's not recommended to mix packages.
- copies the whole `subprocess.py` file instead of just patching the needed calls

Apart from that it's a 5 minute job and it works. I recommend that you keep that as a temporary solution and you do something about this "code that cannot be changed" at some point.

Answer (score 1):

You could replace `subprocess.Popen` with a custom function that suppresses `stdout` and `stderr`:

```
import subprocess
import inspect

def Popen(*args, **kwargs):
    sig = inspect.signature(real_popen)
    bound_args = sig.bind(*args, **kwargs).arguments
    bound_args['stdout'] = subprocess.DEVNULL
    bound_args['stderr'] = subprocess.DEVNULL
    return real_popen(**bound_args)

real_popen = subprocess.Popen
subprocess.Popen = Popen
```

Caveat:

If you have code that attempts to read the process's output, it will fail.