# Python: Suppress library output not using stdout

Tags: python, python-2.7, stdout, visa, pyvisa

I am having problems using `pyVisa` library for port communication, because it sometimes output alot of repeated information to the console (e.G):

> Comm::LockCheck: sess=122e248, isDevSess=0, locssess=0, pid=6220, lockpid=0
>
> Devsess can be locked.
>
> Intfsess can be locked.

I have tried redirecting stdout as suggested in alot of other post (e.g):

```
@contextlib.contextmanager
def suppress_stdout():
with open(os.devnull, "w") as devnull:
    old_stdout = sys.stdout
    sys.stdout = devnull
    try:  
        yield
    finally:
        sys.stdout = old_stdout
```

This suppresses my own `print` commands when used, but does not prevent the library from printing.

Preferably any suggestion should be safe to use in Thread. (I known that the attempted code is not)

Comment: probably because the library is using native commands / code which issues `printf`s, not accounted in python output.

Comment: I have tried to answer by a hack here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45881274/remove-output-of-all-subprocesses-in-python-without-access-to-code/45881484#45881484

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre it seems that the library does not use the subprocess.py or atleast, I can't figure out a way to force the use of the copied file. 
The package is installed in pythonpath under lib, and is actually a wrapper for a seperate library, which I don't have the source files for.