# How to stop NLTK from outputting to terminal when downloading data?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, stderr

When I run my program, which is using:

```
nltk.download('wordnet')
from nltk.corpus import wordnet
```

I get the following output to my terminal:

```
[nltk_data] Downloading package wordnet to
[nltk_data]     /Users/.../nltk_data...
[nltk_data]   Package wordnet is already up-to-date!
```

My program relies on not having this information saved to the terminal and a resulting output file, so how can I prevent the above lines from occurring, or write it to `sys.stderr` so it doesn't get included instead of it being through `print`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A much better solution is suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47616241/771848).

---

*Old Answer:*

According to the [source code](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/downloader.py#L666), `nltk` downloader uses straightforward `print()` calls to report progress. This means that there is no logger involved which you can control or pre-configure.

One of the options is to modify the `sys.stdout` temporarily on the fly -
 there is that [`redirect_stdout()` context manager](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.redirect_stdout) in Python 3.4+:

```
from contextlib import redirect_stdout
import os

import nltk
from nltk.corpus import wordnet


with redirect_stdout(open(os.devnull, "w")):
    nltk.download('wordnet')
```

Or some other options:

- [Suppress calls to print (python)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8391411/771848)
- [Silence the stdout of a function in Python without trashing sys.stdout and restoring each function call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2828953/silence-the-stdout-of-a-function-in-python-without-trashing-sys-stdout-and-resto)

Comment: `redirect_stderr` instead of `redirect_stdout` worked for me

Answer (score 48):

Use `quiet=True`:

```
import nltk
nltk.download('wordnet', quiet=True)
```

Comment: The accepted answer didn't work for me, but this much cleaner solution did work.

Comment: Much cleaner solution that most of the others. I did not know the argument existed. Thanks.