# How to suppress matlab output from python

Tags: python, matlab

Suppose that you have the following .m script:

```
% foo.m
function foo = run()
    disp('Hello!!');
    foo = 1;
end
```

Now, you execute foo.m from python with:

```
import matlab.engine
eng = matlab.engine.start_matlab()
py_foo = eng.foo()
```

This code will set `py_foo = 1` AND will display the output `Hello`. How do I suppress matlab output?

Comment: Put a semicolon after `foo = 1;` in the matlab script?

Comment: No. It was a typo that after `foo = 1` I missed the semicolon. I mean, the output I see comes from `disp('foo')` but I don't want it.  I'll modify my question to make it less confusing.

Comment: Maybe this can help you: [Silence the stdout of a function in Python without trashing sys.stdout and restoring each function call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2828953/silence-the-stdout-of-a-function-in-python-without-trashing-sys-stdout-and-resto)

Comment: @Georgy yes, can work. Not sure since redirection is only for python system output/error. Let OP try that :)

Comment: Thank @Georgy. I'll let you know if i solved that way.

Comment: please let us know so we can close the question as a duplicate (without downvotes :))

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work.

Comment: I found the solution. I just needed to specify the value for the `stdout` argument in the function call. In this case, i can solve with: `eng.foo(stdout=io.stringIO())`

Comment: It will be cool if you move your comment to an answer and self-accept it. That can be valuable for future users.

Comment: @Anton. You're right. I've provided my anwer and I've expanded it a bit. Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I answer my question.

I didn't read carefully the matlab documentation about the Python API. Following the instruction at [this page](https://it.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/redirect-standard-output-and-error-to-python.html), the correct answer to my question is:

```
import matlab.engine
import io

eng = matlab.engine.start_matlab(stdout=io.StringIO())
py_foo = eng.foo()
```

Out:

```
// no output! :D
```

Just in case you are using `exec()` (and be very sure about user inputs in this case), remember to `import io` inside the string passed to exec(), i.e.:

```
import matlab.engine
import io // this is useless!!

eng = matlab.engine.start_matlab()
str = "import io;eng.foo(stdout=io.stringIO())" // put it here
loc = {}
exec(str, {"eng" : eng}, loc)
py_foo = loc["foo"]
```

Comment: This answer seems outdated (or plain wrong). `start_matlab` only accepts `async` and `background` as kwargs (I'm using version 2020a). The link that @Neb provides shows the correct usage, i.e. supply the kwargs `stdout` and `stderr` for every call to the engine. There doesn't seem to be a proper way to disable output alltogether.

Comment: @mkl At the time I posted this answer (Apr '18), this solution worked with Matlab '18 and the corresponding matlab engine. I cannot guarantee it will work on any future version and I do not think this is a valid reason to downvote.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of completeness, and for those who may come across this question, I wanted to leave the working solution here (working as of today, 2023-12-06).
It is a combination of the answer by @Neb and the comment by @mkl.

What worked for me is the following code snippet:

```py
import matlab.engine
import io
import os

eng = matlab.engine.start_matlab()
# optional: add a directory to the Matlab path
eng.addpath(eng.genpath(os.path.dirname(__file__)))
# Pass this stdout parameter, and eventually stderr, with every call
eng.foo(stdout=io.StringIO())
```