# Suppress printing in a MATLAB program when calling from Python

Tags: python, matlab, printing

I am calling a MATLAB program from a Python script using [MathWorks's engine](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/call-matlab-functions-from-python.html). The MATLAB program prints many lines, which I'd like to suppress. I tried the top two answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8391411/), and they did not work. Here's a simple demo:

```matlab
% test.m

function test()
    fprintf('printing in MATLAB\n');
end
```

```py
# test.py

from   matlab import engine
import os
import sys


class suppressPrinting:
    def __enter__(self):
        self._original_stdout = sys.stdout
        sys.stdout = open(os.devnull, 'w')

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        sys.stdout.close()
        sys.stdout = self._original_stdout


eng = engine.start_matlab()

with suppressPrinting():
    print('printing in Python')  # Will be suppressed correctly.

with suppressPrinting():
    eng.test(nargout=0)  # Will *not* be suppressed.
```

If you run `test.py`, it will still print "printing in MATLAB". The statement "printing in Python" will be suppressed. Is there a way to suppress the MATLAB outputs?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49630115/how-to-suppress-matlab-output-from-python does this answer your question ?

Comment: Yes, thank you! That didn't come up in my searches, but it's exactly right.