# Supress output from function

Tags: python, decorator, timeit

there is a thing I want to eliminate, it is when the function print to output, I know about overriding **`sys.stdout.write`** which `print()` function uses. but I think this isn't an ideal fix for this. I'm looking for the ideal pythonic way for doing this?

```
from timeit import Timer
from functools import partial

def timing_decorator(function):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        # print(function)
        callable_f = partial(function, *args, **kwargs)
        # print(dir(Timer))
        total = Timer(callable_f).timeit(1)
        print(total)
        return total
    return wrapper

# example function
@timing_decorator
def hello(arg):
    print(arg)
    return

hello('hi')
```

This outputs:

```
hi
0.00036
```

My expected output would be:

```
0.00036
```

Comment: your function has a line that shows `print(arg)`, if you don't want it to print the `arg` then remove that line

Comment: @gold_cy i know about that, i want to suppress that without removing the print() function

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Silence the stdout of a function in Python without trashing sys.stdout and restoring each function call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2828953/silence-the-stdout-of-a-function-in-python-without-trashing-sys-stdout-and-resto). Putting [vaultah's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28321717/4518341) in your decorator worked for me.

Comment: Please don't vandalize your own posts. When you post here, you give SO the right to distribute the content under CC-by SA 4.0. Any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to delete your question there is a 'delete' link just below the question text.

Comment: @greg-449 Sorry boss but StackOverflow says that I cannot delete unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

We can use `patch` from the `unittest` module of the standard library to override the `print` functionality *only* when calling a function that uses this wrapper by using a context-manager. However, with that being said, the approach that @kindall takes is preferred as it is more Pythonic given this answer is using something inherently meant for testing purposes.

```
from unittest.mock import patch

def timing_decorator(function):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        # print(function)
        callable_f = partial(function, *args, **kwargs)
        with patch('__main__.print'):
            total = Timer(callable_f).timeit(1)
        print(f"{function.__name__}: {total:.5f}ms")
        return total
    return wrapper
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a file-like object that has a `write()` method that does nothing, and have your decorator substitute that for `sys.stdout` (and restore the original stdout after calling the function).

```
import sys

class NoOutput:
    def write(text):
        pass

no_output = NoOutput()

def timing_decorator(function):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        callable_f = partial(function, *args, **kwargs)
        old_stdout, sys.stdout = sys.stdout, no_output
        try:
            total = Timer(callable_f).timeit(1)
        finally:
            sys.stdout = old_stdout
        print(f"{function.__name__}: {total:.5f}ms")
        return total
    return wrapper
```

Note use of `try`/`finally` to make sure stdout gets restored even if an exception is raised in the function.