# Possability hidden print( or don't print) on screen when some functions use "print" in python?

Tags: python

I use a function call by API and provided by another party and no way to change it.
for example, i use:

```
import api
...
api.login()
data=api.getData() #retry itself until success
```

The function will retry itself and print status every 1 sec until success, normally run at least 30 sec. 
I not want too many print out that I hard to troubleshoot. Is it possible to hidden printout under "getData()"?

Comment: Figure out what logging library they're using/logger and configure their logging to go to stderr.

Comment: There are plenty of related questions, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6796492/temporarily-redirect-stdout-stderr , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2828953/silence-the-stdout-of-a-function-in-python-without-trashing-sys-stdout-and-resto

Comment: thank you. i dont really understand the relation of sys.stdout and print(). However, it works.

Answer (score 0):

i find the solution in Demi-Lune comments, thank you.
it just add some code between the call function.

```
import sys
import api

...

api.login()

save_stdout = sys.stdout
sys.stdout = open('trash', 'w')
data=api.getData() #retry itself until success
sys.stdout = save_stdout
```