# Remove the initial text when using the nltk.book module in python

Tags: python, nltk

I'm learning about NLP and messing around with nltk but just by importing the module on my program, whenever I run the script I get the following text:

```
*** Introductory Examples for the NLTK Book ***
Loading text1, ..., text9 and sent1, ..., sent9
Type the name of the text or sentence to view it.
Type: 'texts()' or 'sents()' to list the materials.
text1: Moby Dick by Herman Melville 1851
text2: Sense and Sensibility by Jane Austen 1811
text3: The Book of Genesis
text4: Inaugural Address Corpus
text5: Chat Corpus
text6: Monty Python and the Holy Grail
text7: Wall Street Journal
text8: Personals Corpus
text9: The Man Who Was Thursday by G . K . Chesterton 1908
```

I know it's information about the module, but it's not necessary for me right now. Is there a way to make it so the console doesn't print it when I run the script?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not possible to remove the output message directly via `nltk` (as of August 2021). If you look at the code for [`nltk/book.py`](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/2742fba034b8a320ab91b35df5e6a14c186de01c/nltk/book.py#L22-L25), you'll see the prints statements responsible for the message are written at the top level (global scope). When a module is first imported, all the code at the top level is executed (as if it were a script). So, the first time you import something from `nltk.book`, those print statements will execute.

While you can't prevent those print statements from executing, you could "catch" the output and prevent it from writing to stdout. I would highly advise against this, you don't want to end up in a situation where a warning/error message is printed to stdout as a result of the import, but it get's thrown away silently, and you end up scratching your head for hours trying to solve a weird bug that could've been prevented if you saw the error message. However, if you really want, [here are some ways of doing so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2828953/silence-the-stdout-of-a-function-in-python-without-trashing-sys-stdout-and-resto).

Comment: I see. I guess I'll just live with it then. Thank you